# How to do multi line pattern searching using awk in unix?

Tags: awk

I have to search for a multi-line pattern in my sql script using `awk`.

Sample script-

```
select * from dept where department_name in ('abc'
, 'xyz', 'def') ;
```

In the above example I have to search for the pattern `department_name in` upto the closing bracket `)` and there can be multiple occurrences of this pattern in the script.

The values in the 'IN' clause will span multiple-lines in the above example.

Comment: you want to search pattern only inside the ( ) ??

Comment: No, i want to search from "department_name" to the first closing bracket ")" and this can span across multiple lines.

Comment: can you give the multiple line example and which pattern you want to match and what is the expected output

Comment: I have given an example in the question.

Comment: your example didn't match your comment ----- and this can span across multiple lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the SQL uses `;` as statement delimiters:

```
$ cat statements.sql
First bit;
Second thing;

More
of the same;

select * from dept where department_name in ('abc'
, 'xyz', 'def') ;

Getting to the end;

The
End;
```

Then you may use `;` as the record separator in `awk` and just match as usual:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS=";" } /department_name in ([^)]+)/ { print $0 ";" }' statements.sql


select * from dept where department_name in ('abc'
, 'xyz', 'def') ;
```

The pattern, `/department_name in ([^)]+)/` matches the string `department_name in (` followed by one or several characters that are not `)` (including newlines), followed by a single `)`.

The `print` statement adds `;` to the end of the record since that `;` was removed by `awk` (it removes all record separators).

You'll get a few extra blank lines since there were blank lines after the preceding `;` in the file. You can filter them out with `sed -n '/[[:graph:]]/p'`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS=";"} /department_name in ([^)]+)/ { print $0 ";" }' statements.sql |
  sed -n '/[[:graph:]]/p'
select * from dept where department_name in ('abc'
, 'xyz', 'def') ;
```

Comment: can u explain how this pattern works "department_name in ([^)]+)"

Comment: @PankajPandey Updated the answer.

Comment: but as far as I know the default behaviour of awk is that it does pattern matching line by line (one single line at a time).. then how can your regex span multiple lines.

Comment: @PankajPandey It reads records, and the default record separator (`RS`) is a newline. I'm changing the record separator to `;`. Newlines becomes just another character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` and the record separator `RS`:

```
$ cat << EOT | awk -v RS="department_name|)" 'NR%2==0'
> select * from dept where department_name in ('abc' , 
> 'xyz', 
> 'def') ;
> EOT
in ('abc' , 
'xyz', 
'def'
```

`RS` is set to either `department_name` or `)`, this way the record can be composed with multiple lines.

Provided that you don't have twice same tag, `NR%2=0` will print everything in between the 2 different tags.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the answer you searching for:

```
grep -oE 'department_name.*\)' file_name
```

P.S do not know awk solution to this.